# specify format when converting entity's DateTime column to string type

Tags: .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-migrations

I have an EF6 code first datamodel that has a table Foo containing a Date property, like so:

```
public class Foo
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

I've changed the Date property's type to string, and created a new Migration, which is as follows:

```
public partial class v2 : DbMigration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        AlterColumn("dbo.Foo", "Date", c => c.String());
    }

    public override void Down()
    {
        AlterColumn("dbo.Foo", "Date", c => c.DateTime());
    }
}
```

}

This works, but the DateTimes are converted to (as far as I can tell) en-US string representations like "Nov 23 2015  5:39PM".

Is there a way to tell EF to use a different locale for this, or somehow provide it with a format string to use?

Comment: Why not just adjust the strings manually? Just add an extra column "DateString" first. Then var temp = db.Foo.ToList(); Foreach(var f in temp) f.DateString = String.Format(CultureInfo,"{0:*formatstring*",f.Date);

Comment: I've thought about that as a last resort, but when you have many columns that need to have their type changed, this becomes an insane amount of work. It'd be far more convenient if you could provide EF with a locale or format string.

Comment: That doesn't even compile. ColumnBuilder.String() doesn't take a string format argument.

Answer (score 1):

When used with SQL Server as a backend, EF only creates this instruction for SQL Server:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Foo ALTER COLUMN Date NVARCHAR(max)
```

And it's SQL server which converts the original date into string. And there is no way to change the format. It doesn't have into account nor the connection language, neither the column collation. So I think that SQL Server cannot be instructed to change the format at all.

Unfortunately there is no way to instruct SQL Server how to do it, and you need to do it by hand.

However, this little SQL snippet shows how you would do it using T-SQL:

```
-- Create a table for this demo
CREATE TABLE Foo 
( 
Id INT IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
Date DATETIME)

-- Add some sample data
INSERT INTO Foo (Date) VALUES('2015-11-24T10:20:30.40')
INSERT INTO Foo (Date) VALUES('2015-11-26T11:22:33.44')
INSERT INTO Foo (Date) VALUES('2015-11-28T12:24:36.48')

-- This shows what you'd do with T-SQL

-- Add this before alter column, to store the original value
ALTER TABLE Foo ADD temp DATETIME
UPDATE Foo SET temp = Date

-- This is what EF migration does:
ALTER TABLE Foo ALTER COLUMN Date NVARCHAR(100)

-- Do this to update the changed column value
UPDATE Foo SET Date = FORMAT(temp,'dd/mm/yyyy')
--and this to drop the temp column
ALTER TABLE Foo DROP COLUMN temp

-- See the results
SELECT * FROM Foo

-- Drop the demo table
DROP TABLE Foo
```

So you need to modify the `Up()` method by adding some SQL Execution before and after the `AlterColumn()`:

```cs
Sql("ALTER TABLE Foo ADD temp DATETIME");
Sql("UPDATE Foo SET temp = Date");
AlterColumn("dbo.Foo", "Date", c => c.String());
Sql("UPDATE Foo SET Date = FORMAT(temp,'dd/mm/yyyy')");
Sql("ALTER TABLE Foo DROP COLUMN temp");
```

*NOTE: I use the `FORMAT` function. Depending on your SQL Server version you may need to use other function*

*NOTE: if there is a chance that you make a down migration, youmodify the `Down()` method: convert the string to the format that SQL Server understands, alter the column*

As you need to repeat this for many instances, you could create a helper method to execute the pre and post SQL. EF Migrations has no way to make this automatically. The code generates the `ALTER COLUMN` sql is:

```
`SqlServerMigrationSqlGenerator.Generate(AlterColumnOperation alterColumnOperation)`
```

If you have a lot of instances, you could donwload the code from codeplex, and modify this method to include the pre and post SQL. The `alterColumnOperation` parameter has enough information about the table, column, type, etc. You could do something like this:

```
            if (alterColumnOperation.Column.ClrType == typeof(DateTime)
                && alterColumnOperation.Column.ClrType == typeof(string))
            {
                writer.Write("ALTER TABLE ");
                writer.Write(Name(alterColumnOperation.Table));
                writer.Write(" ADD ");
                writer.Write(Quote("TMP__" + column.Name));
                writer.Write(BuildColumnType(column));
                writer.WriteLine();
                writer.Write("UPDATE ");
                writer.Write(Name(alterColumnOperation.Table));
                writer.Write(" SET ");
                writer.Write(Quote("TMP__" + column.Name));
                writer.Write(string.Format(" = FORMAT({0},'dd/mm/yyyy')"),
                    Quote("TMP__" + column.Name));
            }
```